# Wrong output wth group by and aggregate function in spatialite

Tags: sql, spatialite, grouping

I have a grid and for every cell I want to set the column "landuse" according to the largest intersecting polygon.

```
SELECT 
  grid.PKUID, 
  landuse.landuse,
  MAX(AREA(INTERSECTION(grid.Geometry,landuse.geom)))
FROM grid, landuse
WHERE Overlaps(grid.Geometry,landuse.geom) OR WITHIN(grid.Geometry,landuse.geom) OR  INTERSECTS(grid.Geometry,landuse.geom) 
GROUP BY grid.PKUID
```

Without the max() the table would look like this

```
PKUID | landuse | AREA(INTERSECTION(grid.Geometry,landuse.geom))
168     mais      0.14
168     wheat     0.04   
...
```

and this is what i get with the above query:

```
PKUID | landuse | MAX(AREA(INTERSECTION(grid.Geometry,landuse.geom)))
168     wheat     0.14
...
```

so the maximum value is selected but it doesn't tale the corresponding landuse. I PostgreSQL i would need to write the group part like this

```
GROUP BY grid.PKUID, landuse.landuse
```

but when I do this in my Spatialite query the aggregate function doesn't work and the result looks like i wouldn't have used it.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use an aggregate function with a GROUP BY clause and multiple results are available for the aggregate function, the last of the values is the one that's returned. That's why you're getting "wheat" for the pk_uid 168. 
What you can do to get the actual Max() value for the correct landuse is use a sorted subquery, and do the GROUP BY in the outer query like this:

```
SELECT t.pkuid, t.landuse, t.LU_Area
FROM (SELECT 
  g.PKUID AS pkuid, l.landuse AS landuse,
  AREA(INTERSECTION(g.Geometry,l.geom)) AS LU_Area
  FROM grid AS g JOIN landuse AS l 
  ON INTERSECTS(g.Geometry,l.Geometry)
  ORDER BY pkuid, LU_Area ASC
  ) AS t
GROUP BY t.pkuid;
```

BTW: I didn't understand why you need both Overlaps(), Within() AND Intersects() ??

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. The three different methods were just left over from trying them out, but intersects() alone is enough.